# When to use system() and when to use execv*()?

Tags: c, exec, unix

I need to execute a unix command with different args in a loop. Now I wonder if I should use execvp(), passing in the cmd and the args, or use system, building a string consisting of cmd + args?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the other answers are *mostly* correct.

System, while not only `fork`s and then `exec`s, it doesn't `exec` your process, it runs the default shell, passing your program as an argument.

So, unless you really want a shell (for parameter parsing and the like) it is *much* more efficient to do something like:

```
int i = fork();
if ( i != 0 ) {
    exec*(...); // whichever flavor fits the bill
} else {
    wait(); // or something more sophisticated
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `exec` family of functions will replace the current process with a new one, whilst `system` will fork off the new process, and then wait for it to finish. Which one to use depends on what you want.

Since you're doing this in a loop, I guess you don't want to replace the original process. Therefore, I suggest you try to go with `system`.

Comment: system also subjects the line to command line parsing, which might open up holes for injection attacks.

Comment: I looked for some tutorials on this on the web and most examples fork()ed a new process and than replaced the fork with execvp(). After that, the parent process waited for the child process to finish. Is this basically what system() does?

Comment: Yes, that is basically what `system()` does.  Calling `system()` also runs the default shell and passes your program as the argument, which will create a bit more overhead.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use execvp only if I can't achieve what I want with system.  Note that to get the equivalent of system, you need execvp, fork and some signal handling as well.